# Chisel: Compiling Chisel library on Windows

Tags: scala, chisel

I have been using sbt on windows and a custom build.sbt script in conjunction with an import Chisel._ in the top-level file in order to generate Verilog from my Chisel source successfully.

I'm trying to get an IDE working on Windows to expedite Chisel development. I've gone with the Eclipse based SCALA IDE http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html/

I want to compile the Chisel library so that the import Chisel._ can be resolved locally, without having to go off and download the source from the repository each timeand recompile the source. When I download the Chisel-master repo from Git and include the src\main folder in my SCALA project in the SCALA IDE, I get lots of syntax errors in the Chisel SCALA files that prevent me from building the project.

Has anyone done anything like this before on Windows or have any knowledge of working with the SCALA IDE as it may just be a case of undefined symbols in the project configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you did with build.sbt respect to recompile (I think it download it only the first time, then it caches it for the future).  But I'm using ScalaIDE for Chisel on linux, using the default build.sbt files, maybe you can try to get it working out of the box first to help narrow down the issue.

Here are the steps I took in order to get ScalaIDE work with Chisel:

1. the latest Scala IDE uses 2.11.8, the current Chisel repository defaults to 2.11.7.  So I had to change all the build.sbt reference to scalaVersion from 2.11.7 to 2.11.8
2. I used sbteclipse 
   https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse
   To create importable the workspace to setup the compilation dependencies.
3. Except for chiselFrontEnd.  For some reason, this package is not added to the dependency. I have to Add chiselFrontEnd as a javabuildpath dependency manually (Properties/JavaBuildPath, under Projects) for my own projects.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve undefined symbols, you can also add a JAR onto the project build path using Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs...

If you are getting your JARs through Maven / SBT, they should be in:

`C:\Users\<name>\.ivy2\local\edu.berkeley.cs\chisel3_2.11\jars`

If you are using publish-local with chisel3, your JARs should be in

`C:\Users\<name>\.ivy2\cache\edu.berkeley.cs\chisel3_2.11\jars`

Note that chisel3 is compiled into one JAR, including coreMacros and chiselFrontend sub-projects

Of course, this is a more quick-and-dirty solution compared to something that can parse SBT files.